# How do I get the value of a line in a RecyclerView with a switch button?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which get data from my firebase database.
However, I need the ID of the line when I press the respective switch button in a line.

[image]

And here is my code so far. But now I don't know how I can get the value of a row so that I can update my firebase with the new data.

```
  status_.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: implement that logic when you bind the viewholder

Comment: @a_local_nobody YOU MAKE MY DAY!!! Thanks